# Javascript - assign href

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to assign href to a div element but the code does not assign the href. Any idea why?

```
<div id="AllSearch" > Search All </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}

alert(getQueryVariable("k"));
var strurl = "http://search.Zark.it/pages/results.aspx?k=";
var urlEverything = strurl.concat(getQueryVariable("k"));
alert (urlEverything);
var x = document.getElementById("AllSearch");
//document.getElementById("AllSearch").href = "http://www.cnn.com";
x.href = urlEverything;
</script>
```

Comment: `href` is a property of `<a>`. `<div>` doesn't have it.

Comment: Nitpick: `return(false);` Return is not a method. It should just be `return false`

Comment: `<div href="derp">` totally works... right? ... Didn't think so.

Comment: @epascarello - `return(false)` is perfectly fine

Comment: Why are you trying to assign an `href` to a `<div>` element? What problem is that intended to solve?

Comment: Politely: you missed a typo — change `<div id="AllSearch" > Search All </div>` to `<a id="AllSearch" > Search All </a>`

Comment: Thanks all for your help and href about the div. changed it <a> and it's works like charm. I appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like the div to be clickable, you can put it within an `a` tag.
Then change the value of the `a` tag's `href` attribute:

```js
document.getElementById('link').href = 'changed';
```

```html
<a id='link'><div>hello</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `div` element doesn't have the `href` attribute, but `a` element does

see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) for `div` and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) for `a`

Answer (score 0):

you can  use `setAttribute`

```js
document.getElementById('link').setAttribute("href", "www.google.com")
```

```html
<a id='link'>a's href was changed</a>
```